# Javascript adding an element outside the foreach but they concatenate instead of adding

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, concatenation, addition

I have a foreach

```
var a= [38, 34, 22, 19];
Array.forEach(function (b){
  b= a+ b;  
  a.push(b);
});
```

But when the results are

```
["38", "3834", "38,383422", "38,3834,38,38342219"]
```

How can I stop them concatenating and have a result of

```
["38, "72", "94", "119"]
```

Comment: Not getting what you are trying to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.forEach` will throw an error.Use map function.Hopefully following snippet will be useful.

Also `a.push(b);` will push in the same array

```js
var a = [38, 34, 22, 19];
// create a variable to store the updated value
var tempNum = 0;
//use map which will return a new array
var m = a.map(function(b) {
  //update tempValue with new value
  tempNum = tempNum + b
  return tempNum; // return tempNum
});
console.log(m)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` as well

```js
var a= [38, 34, 22, 19];
var output = a.reduce( (ac,c,i) => ( ac.push(ac.length == 0 ? c : c + ac[i-1] ) , ac ) , [] );

console.log(output);
```